# Installation of GMS2 and 3 on the same computer

Tags: dm-script

I would like to know the benefit of GMS 3 offline versus GMS 2. And if 
it is possible to install GMS 2 and GMS 3 offline on the same computer.

Thank you
Eric

Comment: This is not really a suitable question for this site. StackOverflow is about *coding* in general, and the [DM-script] tag is for *coding in DigitalMicrgraph*. Your question is more suitable as service request to Gatan (there is a link on their homepage.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, provided you have liceneses for both which are given for the identical site-ID.

Usually, you can just install one, then copy (or rename) the installation folder (`C:\Program Files\Gatan\`) into something else, and then install the other.
You launch each version from the respective subfolder.

**However**: Both versions will use the *same* data-folder (`C:\ProgramData\Gatan`) and hence the *same* preference file (including installed scripts and the global tags). You might expect some issues here depending on your particlar situation.

Be a bit more cautious when you want to do that on a PC connected to microscope hardware. You might then need to re-register some particular DLLs before each switchover.